# Create Opposite Method to Signify Days Off?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, text, methods

How can I create a method that takes all noncommitted days?

### challenge.rb

```
def self.committed_for_today
  today_name = Date::ABBR_DAYNAMES[Date.current.wday].downcase
  ids = all.select { |h| h.committed.include? today_name }.map(&:id)
  where(id: ids)
end 

def self.noncommitted_for_today
  ??? # Something with editing this line maybe to include not current Date [Date.current.wday]?
end
```

I want to distinguish challenges that are suppose to be done today to those that are not suppose to be done. When a user creates a challenge he chooses which days he is `:committed` to: `t.text     "committed",       default: "---\n- sun\n- mon\n- tue\n- wed\n- thu\n- fri\n- sat\n"`

### controller

```
@challenges_today = current_user.challenges.committed_for_today.select{ |challenge| challenge.date_started <= Date.today }
@challenges_not_today = current_user.challenges.noncommitted_for_today.select{ |challenge| challenge.date_started <= Date.today }
```

### view

```
<% @challenges_today.each do |challenge| %>
  # color: blue
<% end %>

<% @challenges_not_today.each do |challenge| %>
  # color: gray, to signify he has a challenge just not for today
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should execute that query in the DB directly. With your `committed_for_today` method you load ALL Challenges from DB into memory. Then you select some IDs and then you reload those again.

How about

```
def self.committed_for_today
  today_name = Date::ABBR_DAYNAMES[Date.current.wday].downcase
  where('committed like ?', "%#{today_name}%")
end
```

and

```
def self.noncommitted_for_today
  today_name = Date::ABBR_DAYNAMES[Date.current.wday].downcase
  where('committed not like ?', "%#{today_name}%")
end
```

?

If you can change the DB schema, then i'd suggest you change the way you store '''committed`. Either add flags`commited_monday``` use a JSON datatype (postgres) and store a hash or use a different table (weekdays) that you can reference.

Comment: See my answer. The implementation i proposed should work with the current DB. It uses SQL ```like``` feature which can be used to search for a pattern. See http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

Comment: updated my answer. use today_date instead of query. If you want you can keep the existing method as is. but it is not efficient and will cause problems when you have lots of challenges.